# Python plot data against HH:MM time from text file

Tags: python, matplotlib, time

I have a text file with time of day HH:MM in column 0 and values in columns 1 and 2. I need to plot each of 1 and 2 against the time, as bars, with the data from 2 overlaying the data from 1.

I can't import the text file because of the time format. How do I get Python to recognise that column 0 is time? After a lot of Googling I still haven't been able to find a solution.

```
import datetime

t,s,l=np.loadtxt('longruntextfile.tsv',delimiter='\t',unpack=True)
#t = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M') for elem in t]

print(t)
```

I've put my code above, you can see where I tried to use some stuff I found online. If someone knows how to make this work I'll be so grateful.

Comment: 1.  what's `np`
2.  please give the sample data of your `longruntextfile.tsv`

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M')` what happens when you execute that list comprehension? Did you look at the datetime.datetime.strptime documentation? Please takwe the time to read [mcve] - how can we help when we don't know what your tsv looks like?

Comment: np? my guess is that OP imported numpy as np.

Comment: @NicoNing np is numpy, it's imported in another cell of my notebook.

The whole dataset has about 700 points but here's a snippet:

12:48 9.616131652 1.296041247
12:49 9.654977575 1.380795988
12:50 9.577285729 1.331355723
12:51 9.580817177 1.313698485
12:52 9.496062436 1.30663559
12:53 9.089945969 1.211286506
12:54 8.934562277 1.154783346
12:55 8.779178585 1.108874528
12:56 8.50019423 1.165377688

Answer (score 0):

```
# arq.txt row -> 10:15,A,B

from datetime import datetime
with open('arq.txt', 'r') as arq:
    row = arq.read()
    cols = row.split(',')
    # if you need time not string
    # time = datetime.strptime(cols[0], "%H:%M") 
    print("Time: {}  |  Col_1: {}  |  Col_2: {}".format(cols[0], cols[1], cols[2]))
    #just plot cols[]
arq.close()
```

`Time: 10:15  |  Col_1: A  |  Col_2: B`

Hope this helps

Comment: This is fantastic except for the fact that I only get back the first row of my data, so can only plot one data point. Any idea how to get all of them?

Comment: Edit: I did it by using your method on a text file with only the times in it and a separate text file with my data imported with np.loadtxt :)

Thank you for your help!